# Dragging down values from array referenced using table column

Tags: microsoft-excel, array

Let's say I have an excel table I called People and it has 3 columns (Name, Age, Height).

Now I want to create another table (let's call it Job) where one of the columns is also Name, and I want to fill the Name column in Job dynamically based on the Name column in People as I increase the number of rows Job has.

So for example, if People[Name] has {"Peter","Paul","Jake"}, then I want Job[Name] to start filling in those names as I add rows.

Example of what I've tried:

```
={CHOOSE(ROW()-ROW(Job[#Headers]),People[[Name]:[Name]])}
```

My thoughts were to use the choose function and for the values reference People[Name] for the names I'm interested in dynamically copying. Then, the index_num `ROW()-ROW(Job[#Headers])` is using the row index of the cell in the Name column of the Job table minus the row index of the headers column of the job table to identify the relevant index for the targeted Name column in the People table. I don't have to use choose, but I couldn't think of another way to do this and my attempt is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CHOOSE is the wrong function.

Instead use INDEX:

```
=INDEX(People[[Name]:[Name]],ROW()-ROW(Job[#Headers]))
```

INDEX is made to accept a range or array in the first argument and return the relative result depending on the number in the second and/or optional third argument.

Comment: I feel so stupid for not considering that! I'm used to using index with row/column and completely forgot you could use it to index an array. Thank you!!!